# Posting on user's wall doesn't fail but doesn't who either

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm having an issue where I'm posting a new message using facebook SDK 6.0 with:

```
var client = new FacebookClient("<target users access token>")
{
    AppId = "<my app id>",
    AppSecret = "<my app secret>"
};
var args = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"message", "A message",
        };
dynamic postResult = client.Post("/me/feed", args);
```

The interesting part is that the postResult has an id property, but the message doesn't appear on the users feed/wall. Using the API to get all feeds doesn't return the post and manually viewing it using https://graph.facebook.com/[message_id] simple returns "false".

I've tried this with sandbox mode on and off and it makes to difference.

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I transliterated the example from https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/ into Java code that uses the Apache HttpClient to POST and GET the user's feed. Both requests return 200s, but they have no effect on the user's feed. The GET comes back empty, even though I logged in as the user via the web and posted some status messages from there. The user is a test user I created for our app.